# How to type Euro symbol in keyboard that only have `$`?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, keyboard, symbols

is there a way to type Euro symbol (something like shortcut) when my keyboard doesn't have that symbol ? My keyboard only have `$`.

Each time I want to type Euro symbol what I do is copy paste from libreoffice Euro symbol. it is fine when writing in libreoffice, but the problem is when writing in simple word processor (like vim, atom, etc)  or in the browser, it is time consuming.

thanks

**EDIT**

My OS is ubuntu and windows (dual boot, sometimes I use windows , sometimes ubuntu) so anything that work for each case or both is fine.

Comment: Try "ALT GR" + "E"

Comment: alt e works only when system language is set to an european one

Comment: I cannot answer, low rep. But in MacOS with US layout you can insert € with OPTION+SHIFT+2

Answer (score 16):

If you are using a full keyboard, you can try this typing

```
Alt + 0128
```

Ref: http://www.irongeek.com/alt-numpad-ascii-key-combos-and-chart.html
http://homepages.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~george/ansi_ascii_character_chart.html

Answer (score 6):

It will also depend on what keyboard layout you have.

UK keyboard on Windows it's ctrl/alt/ 4 clearly marked on the keyboard itself.

Comment: Actually that’s the only thing it depends on. As long as the keyboard generates the correct key press events, at least.

Comment: mhm - I spent a few minutes fumbling around with alt/grp [whatever] & got nowhere… til I actually looked down at the keyboard & found it written on;) On my Mac it's on alt/2 so it seems to like hopping around.

Comment: If you use a layout different from how your keyboard is labeled, the labels won’t help. ;) Apple engineers where probably watching *And Now for Something Completely Different* while designing their keyboard layouts. Or maybe they “thought different”. Who knows.

Comment: Actually, they 'thought sensible' but then someone added a Euro sign & like everybody else, they had nowhere to put it;) - dollar/pound symbols were already on 3 & 4, for both UK & US… so I guess they just put it next door & relegated something

Answer (score 4):

On Windows try <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. On keybords where this shortcut is already used (e.g. on Polish Programmers keybord <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> produces 'ę'), use <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

If this does not work for you, take a look at [How to type the euro sign](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/how-to-type-the-euro-sign-HP005275408.aspx) topic in help for Microsoft Office.

Comment: CTRL + ALT + E worked for me, but only in Word, not in notepad, neither in this comment box, not in Excel. Any more tips how to do that?

Comment: For me it works everywhere - Word, Excel, Notepad, command prompt, any application. Seems it is handled by operating system and not individually by apps. In your case maybe you have a shortcut defined in Word? What keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: I am using a laptop.. Lenovo Thinkpad X230...

Comment: @Firee You can check the keyboard layout you use in Control Panel in regional settings. This is how Windows interprets the keystrokes and what the help topic I mentioned refers to. Imagine the same model of laptop sold in different countries where different diacritical characters are used. All the keyboards have the same internal wiring, the only differences are labels on individual keys and the keyboard layout set in Control Panel.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + E (English layout) or Alt Gr + E (German layout) work both in Word 2016 and Notepad on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which operating system you have (Windows, Linux, OS X, ..). Maybe you could add that information to the question.

On Windows you could try to memorize <kbd>Alt</kbd>+0128 (hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, then type the code on the numerical part on the right side of your keyboard). There are also many utilities to help enter special characters, such as AllChars or UniChars.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I realize different OS has different "how to do it", any way :

- in windows (thanks @Berend and @Charm_quark) press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> then type `0128`
- in [Ubuntu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367384/how-do-i-enter-the-euro-symbol) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> then type `20ac`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Irish keyboard <kbd>Alt GR</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> on Ubuntu possibly UK keyboard as well.