# Alt+U started producing € sign

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

For a long time I have been using <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> as a shortcut for starting an application in my OS. It's the one where you type the name of an app in the `Start` menu, open `Properties` and under `Keyboard shortcut` you bind a key to it (e.g. http://imgsrv.worldstart.com/shutdown_keyboard_shortcut_2.jpg).

But recently it stopped working for no apparent reason (I haven't changed anything). Today I found out that when I press <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in any text editor/field it produces a euro sign: `€`. I don't know if it also did that before when my shortcut worked (i.e. launched my app).

My question is: how do I make my keyboard shortcut work again (i.e. start an app)?

Comment: When you check the shortcut value what does it show?

Comment: What keyboard layouts do you have installed and enabled?

Comment: The shortcut still shows `Ctrl+Alt+U`. I have Polish (Programmer's), same as before.

Comment: What about trying  CTRL  +  ALT +  U  instead ?

Comment: And I susspect you are using an English Keyboard Layout, Double check the keybord layout you are using

Comment: I'm using Polish (Programmer's) keyboard, is keyboard layout something else? How do I check that? As for Ctrl+Alt+U - € again, no shortcut working.

Comment: Are you sure `Ctrl + Alt + U` is properly associated to a shortcut (and that shortcut is working)? For me, this key combination was typing a special letter but when I associated it with a shortcut then it stopped typing that special letter and started launching the program.

Comment: Well, this is weird. Yes, the shortcut was properly assigned (it DID work, for a long time!). And then it suddenly stopped working. But now I tried removing the shortcut altogether and then assigning it again - and now it works. It's weird and I'd like to know what happened and why.

Comment: Was the shortcut working by double clicking on it? If yes, then maybe some update related to language settings might have caused it. Anyways, now that it is fixed, enjoy your hotkeys!

Comment: Oh, I meant keyboard shortcut, not a file linking to exe e.g. on my Desktop. And my OS had no recent update. Or any other significant change.

Comment: You asked this question an year ago. That's a very long time to commit 'no updates, no changes'. Anyways, I think we'll never be able to figure out the root cause of this problem so maybe ignore it and enjoy your hotkeys.

Comment: Have you tried selecting an other keyboard layout to see if `Alt Gr + U` still produces a `€`

Comment: No. But I'm afraid I can't now since resetting the keyboard shortcut made the problem go away. But if that happens again I'll try that. Although, I don't think my keyboard layout is the problem since it worked before (and now works again).

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that you use Polish Programmer keyboard layout, it is by default that <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> produces the euro sign.

Source: http://eurosymbol.eu/keyboard & https://superuser.com/a/848007/481708\

As for why it changed, you might have pressed <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> or other combination that changed your input language accidentally and reset it to the default input for <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> instead of your custom shortcut. Or as others stated it might have been a system update. I guess you should just choose a shortcut that does not conflict with those already assigned by the system, just to be safe that it won't be reset. A tool like ActiveHotkey(http://www.tranglos.com/activehotkeys/) would help view those already assigned.

Comment: activehotkeys only runs on Windows 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Right-Alt</kbd> was since always the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key, defined by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) as:

> a modifier key found on some computer keyboards and is primarily used
>   to type characters that are unusual for the locale of the keyboard
>   layout, such as currency symbols and accented letters.

On the keyboard layouts I tested it on, it gave : English UK - ú, English US
and French - beep.

Evidently something changed in your keyboard layout definition, but I don't
believe it's worthwhile finding out what, because it can just come back.
It this was the result of a Windows Update, then this is a lost cause.

To ensure that this key combination will always work, no matter what is
the keyboard layout, I suggest to download and install [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/),
the ultimate keyboard macro utility.
You could create a a AutoHotkey script in your
Startup folder, for example
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\AutoHotkey startup.ahk`, and store inside the following mapping for 
<kbd>Right-Alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to run your program:

```
RAlt & u::
Run, "\path\to\your\program.exe"
return
```

Comment: AHK for launching a program (when such functionality is built into the OS) is really an overkill.

Comment: @NPS: Once one starts using AHK, one can find more and more uses for it. And it is a sure-fire solution for this problem, when OS changes disabled the old solution.

Comment: Not saying AHK isn't good, it might just be, but if all I want to do is this one thing then it's still an overkill.

Comment: IMHO AHK is a better and more lasting solution than monkeying with Windows. There are utilities that will change your keyboard layout, and maybe you could use one of them to delete the new RAlt-u combination, but I think that AHK is a cleaner solution that does not involve hacking and can later more easily be modified or undone.

Comment: I have looked into several keyboard layout editors: SharpKeys, Keytweak, Key Remapper, Microsoft keyboard layout creator. None of them can undo a key-combination. Meaning that one can nullify the RAlt or u keys, but not the RAlt-u combination. It looks like AHK is left as the only solution.